# Trouble defining enum

Tags: c, enums, typedef

```
typedef enum Colors{black, white};
void chess(int rows, int cols, Colors array[rows][cols]) {
   for (int i = 0; i <  rows; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
           if (i+j % 2 == 0) {
               array[i][j] = black;
           } else {
               array[i][j] = white;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

I am getting an error saying `error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘Colors’`

I have made sure I've declared the enum type correctly, so am not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: typedef enum {black, white} Colors;

Comment: *(I think...)* If you're using a C99 or C++ compiler, just `enum Colors{black, white};`  No need for `typedef` at all.

Comment: N@abelenky Nope that's what I had originally, and I'm using a C99 compiler :)

Comment: @abelenky That would not work for the example.

Comment: `typedef enum { black, white } Colors;` needs in C99.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An enum is normally defined as `enum Colors { black, white };` and has to be referred to by the name `enum Colors` (the `enum` in front is required). For instance:

```
enum Colors { black, white };

void print_color(enum Colors color) {
  if(color == black) {
    printf("Black\n");
  } else if(color == white) {
    printf("White\n");
  }
}
```

Now, the "typedef" syntax is  `typedef enum { black, white } Colors;`, and now we just refer to it by the name `Colors` (no `enum` in front):

```
typedef enum { black, white } Colors;

void print_color(Colors color) {
  if(color == black) {
    printf("Black\n");
  } else if(color == white) {
    printf("White\n");
  }
}
```

This weird syntax is becuase `enum { black, white }` is actually a nameless enum, and the `typedef` keyword gives this nameless type a name.

Comment: what if I'm not using typedef? I had enum Colors {black, white} originally which didn't work either

Comment: The error was the same as the original. I am using a C99 compiler and GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the enum as follows:

```
typedef enum Colors
{
  black,
  white
} my_colors;
```

and use `my_colors`in the function. I think it might help